# MySQL INSERT missing info after switch to utf8mb4

Tags: mysql, pdo, character-encoding, insert, utf8mb4

Im searching all over for an answer to this and still cant seem to find it

> Server : localhost
>   MySQL Version : 5.6.17

I have set my db's tables to **utf8mb4** to graduate to more character possibilities. When i insert certain hashed information into my table, depending on the random sequence of characters in the string, only a fragment of the string actually gets inserted (if not left completely blank).

In my handle for my pdo statement, i do charset=utf8mb4 before prepping my query, and as fail safe i also SET NAMES utf8mb4 before. So i thought everything should be kosher with the CHARSET and COLLATE.

So my question is, what should i be doing to successfully put the entire string into field? Is there some character escaping i should be doing that im missing?

Edit : When i copy/paste the string into phpmyadmin, it successfully puts the entire string in the field.

Comment: example of a srting i try to insert   M^)E¬öJª1t®LÇÕtËe?~Ru4M‚ª ¡Ç5DRE#‘£zcð/Ó,Fà· –ÐoAK£ë¿à¾9Ú

Comment: Really?  That looks more like a `BLOB`, not some form of readable `TEXT` in any current language.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see the hex for the truncated string.

Probably the answer lies in failure to establish that the client is using utf8mb4 via `SET NAMES utf8mb4` or some parameter on the connection call.

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php

Answer (score 0):

OK, so i found the solution i was looking for and feel like an dummy for spending so much time on a fix. Maybe this will help someone traveling down the same path, so i'll post the answer myself.

**More About The Behavior :**

The reason the PDO would fail to put the string in the db field in its entirety was because it was not utf8_encoded. (This is where i felt dumb). Thinking it was already prepped for entry, and all i had to do was bind, was wrong. Instead it would terminate the string at the first unrecognizable character (using utf8mb4), or put the whole string, and replace unrecognizable characters with ? (using just utf8).

**The Solution :**

What i ended up doing was taking the original string, run it through `ut8_encode()` and since this was information provided by the program and not user input, i didnt bother to bind and instead used `$pdoHandle->quote($utf8String)` which prepped it for insertion.

After executing, the whole string was inserted. Now when i select the hashed info, i run `utf8_decode` and have exactly what i inserted in the db.

**Better Practices?**
If you know a better way to approach this solution, im open to hear alternatives. Do please include a bit on why, so i can grasp an understanding of your approach.